# Add a sheet after the last one and copy the last one values not formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy only values (not formulas) of the last sheet and name the new sheet "Games". I'm using this:

```
Sub CreateColumn()
ActiveSheet.Copy
Cells.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


 ActiveSheet.Name = "Games"
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

But it's creating a new Workbook, not a new sheet after the last one. Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Plus, the last sheet is not the one active all the time... could you help me with that too?

Comment: at the moment you copy from activesheet into the same activesheet. 'Last' is really last or it has any name?? do you really need to copy all cells?? maybe only range of data would be faster??

Comment: some additional technical tips: `Sheets(Sheets.Count)` is the last sheet... to copy use `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Copy` and you paste it correctly into active sheet...

Comment: Last is really last, it has a different name every file, but i need the last one everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sheet first.  Something like:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Games"
```

Then activate it to copy into.